# Can't import from fixtures folder a file with simple variables

Tags: javascript, json, cypress

I'm learning Cypress and have a simple problem:

have tags.json file in fixtures folder.

This works:

```
cy.intercept('GET', '**/tags', {
    "tags": [
        "cypress‌",
        "‌‌automation",
        "‌‌‌testing"
    ]
})
```

But this fails to load tags:

```
cy.intercept('GET', '**/tags', 'fixture:tags.json')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're [stubbing a response](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Stubbing-a-response) You have to write like this:

```
cy.intercept('GET', '**/tags', { fixture: 'tags.json' })
```